# Unban the goo.gl URL shortener?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks

[All URL shorteners are now banned on SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services/316905?noredirect=1#comment1038253_316905).  However, this includes **goo.gl**, which is used by default by Google Maps for sharing both directions and points of interest.  Can we get this unbanned on Travel.SE only?

Comment: If there's an abuse concern, perhaps allowing just "goo.gl/maps" would work?

Comment: It's also no longer possible for many users to create new goo.gl short URLs unless they previously used it prior to its discontinuation.

Comment: I have asked a community manager to take a look at this request. Unfortunately this is something that us moderators cannot help with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General goo.gl-shortened URLs are still banned *in post bodies* network-wide (and also in titles, comments, tags and flags on SO).

However, I've added an exception for goo.gl/maps *only* that will allow these to go through. As much as I'd prefer to see folks use the expanded version of these URLs, posting from mobile when these are the easiest URLs to grab makes that an unnecessary burden, and doesn't really add much to the results anyway.

Comment: Thank you for fixing this!